# Select leaf node in compound nodes with cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js, cytoscape, cytoscape-web

I have several compound nodes (A contains B, and B contains C)and I want to select the leaf node (C). How to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you mean by selecting isn't clear, but I'm guessing you mean how to query the graph:

```
cy.nodes().not(':parent'); // all nodes who are not themselves a parent
// or //
cy.nodes(':child').not(':parent'); // all descendant nodes who are not themselves a parent
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to select all leaves, you can use the leaves() method provided by cytoscape: https://js.cytoscape.org/#nodes.leaves

You can use it as follows:

```
cy.nodes().leaves()
```

That will return an array of nodes. So you can either iterate through every one of them or simply select the leaf with the index = 0 (in case you're sure only one leaf is present in your tree).

```
const leaves = cy.nodes().leaves();
leaves.forEach((leaf) => {
  // add 1 to count the node it self.
  console.log('leaf -> ', leaf.data().id, 'deepLevel: ', leaf.predecessors('node').length + 1);
});
```